# Swift : Pressing ENTER creates duplicate code in Xcode 6.4

Tags: xcode6.4

I'm working with Swift using Xcode 6.4.

Whenever `enter/return` key is pressed (also occurs on press of tab key) the code below gets duplicated.

I've tried by deleting duplicated code, adjusting space/tabs but none worked.

Why is this happening? What's the fix?

Screenshot 1 is when I first time encountered this problem.
Screenshot 2 is error occurred the next day.

[image: Screenshot 1 for error]

[image: Screenshot 2 for error]

Comment: I upvoted, I don't know why someone down voted before as it's a genuine good question and a nasty problem. Sorry can't help very much but have you tried this in another file, other project ? Re-installed Xcode ?

Comment: @Glenn : I've tried on different line of code. It happens at times. When I quit Xcode and start working on same code next day it works fine.

Comment: and in another project ?

Comment: @Glenn : I've found work-around for this one. You can check answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

I've found *work-around* for this issue. You have to `press enter/return on place where one line below are empty.` For above issue go to end of `handler` statement and hit enter\return key.

In the above case (question posted) *duplication of code occurs when return\enter key is pressed while cursor is positioned above any line of code.*

This may be *Xcode issue for Swift and might be fixed in Xcode 7* (not tried yet).